# How to keep filtering a java stream until there's only one match?

Tags: java, filter, java-stream

I have a list of objects and I need to choose the one that matches on most conditions. This means that I need to keep filtering until there's only one element left or until there's no elements left - in which case I throw.
I only have 3 levels of filtering as of now, so if by the last filter there's 0 or more than one matches, I throw too. And yes, the order of the filtering matters.

I wrote something that works but I wonder if there's any way of making it prettier or more efficient. Any help appreciated!

```java
List<Object> listOfObjects = getAllObjects();

List<Object> filteredObjects1 =
    emptyIfNull(listOfObjects).stream()
        .filter(filter1())
        .collect(Collectors.toList());

if (filteredObjects1.size() == 1) {
    return filteredObjects1.get(0);
}

if (filteredObjects1.size() == 0) {
    throw new Exception();
}

List<Object> filteredObjects2 =
    emptyIfNull(filteredObjects1).stream()
        .filter(filter2())
        .collect(Collectors.toList());

if (filteredObjects2.size() == 1) {
    return filteredObjects2.get(0);
}

if (filteredObjects2.size() == 0) {
    throw new Exception();
}

List<Object> filteredObjects3 =
    emptyIfNull(filteredObjects1).stream()
        .filter(filter3())
        .collect(Collectors.toList());

if (filteredObjects3.size() == 1) {
    return filteredObjects3.get(0);
} 

throw new Exception();
```

Comment: i m not sure about efficient, but you could probably prettify it by using some sort of chain of responsibility pattern. If the list is not empty, pass it on to next handler until last handler then throw an exception if needed, but it would probably just create more boiler plate code than its worth

Answer (score 1):

This needs a recursive style implementation.

```java
public Object lastRemaining(List<Object> listOfObjects, List< Predicate<Object> > filters, int depth) {
    List<Object> filteredObjects = 
        emptyIfNull(listOfObjects).stream()
            .filter(filters.get(depth) // may get index out of bounds if not enough filters
            .collect(Collectors.toList());

    if (filteredObjects.size() == 1) {
        return filteredObjects.get(0);
    } else if (filteredObjects.isEmpty()) {
        throw new Exception();
    } else {
        return lastRemaining(filteredObjects, filters, ++depth);
    }
}
```

And call it like this:

```java
Predicate<Object> filter1 = o -> o.hashCode() > 5;
Predicate<Object> filter2 = o -> o.hashCode() < 10;
    
filters.add(filter1);
filters.add(filter2);
lastRemaining(getAllObjects(), filters, 0);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simplify your code by not checking for `size() == 0` and have a loop over the filters. A simple method call like this:

```
static Object findOne(List<Object> listOfObjects, Predicate<Object> ... filters) {
    // Ideally use:  Objects.requireNonNull(listOfObjects);
    listOfObjects = emptyIfNull(listOfObjects);
    for (Predicate<Object> filter : filters) {
        listOfObjects = listOfObjects.stream().filter(filter)
                    .collect(Collectors.toList()); // later JDKs: .toList()
        if (listOfObjects.size() == 1) {
            return listOfObjects.get(0);
        }
    }
    throw new RuntimeException("Not found match");
}
```

Call with:

```
Object match = findOne(getAllObjects(), filter1(), filter2(), filter3() /** , ETC */);
```